# How to bind data source to datagridview combobox and checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have one datagridview with combo-box and check box.
[image: DataGRidView]

when i try to get values from datagridview in data table it works fine. But when i tried to get value from database in same scheme of datagridview it adds rows in datagridview but does not sets combo box or check box value. For setting datasource i tried.

`DataTable dt = db.getSecurityCheck(dateTimePickerDate.Value);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

After setting datasource and DataPropertyName with datatable column name it replaces checkbox and combobox with textboxes.
[image: After Setting Datasource].

Do i need to manually set the values by running for each loop on retrieved datatable and setting value for each cell individually.

Comment: I have the same dream that I can do what you are thinking. But it remains a dream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `DataPropertyName` on the columns in the `DataGridView` you have defined to correspond to the `DataTable` columns.

Comment: I want the value to selected in combobox but it replaces combobox with textbox